# Why does depmod keep trying to load deleted modules

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I removed kernel modules installed with rpm using `yum remove kmodname`.
The `*.ko` was located under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/`.

I run `depmod -a` and I get `depmod: ERROR: fstatat(4, kmodname.ko.xz): No such file or directory`

How can I force `depmod` to update its database?

Comment: Same thing can happen in some situations after `dkms uninstall`, FYI for anyone coming across this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have symlinks, probably under one of your kernels' weak-modules, pointing at modules that have been deleted.

Comment: after deleting them from `weak-updates` folder, it's now fine. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3536351